# jQuery change visible state of submit on nestable menus

Tags: jquery, visibility

I'm using the nestable drag + drop list from `DBushell`.

I've got a submit button that I want to appear only if the user starts changing around the list so, once they've finished sorting the list, they can commit the changes to the db.

I hide it to start with in jQuery:

```
$(".dd-submit").hide()
```

Then it builds the menu with:

```
$('#nestable3').nestable({
group: 1
})
.on('change', updateOutput, $(".dd-submit").show());
```

I added in the last bit as I want it to show the `.dd-submit` class when someone manually changes the ordered list as I believed this is the right way to add something else to the same trigger but it doesn't want to know.

Plus it displays the submit button after a few milliseconds of loading the page. It's like it's initially hiding it but it's running the on change before I've done anything on the screen.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: Not without stripping out half the code as it's all using database entries to populate the field.